# Jquery UI draggable element can be dragged past the desired width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have two divs with draggable functionality, but I was wondering, is there any way I can lock them to not be able to be dragged to the right and down? This is the css and js for each draggable div:

```
#the-sheet {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 25px;
  top: 200px;
  left: 250px;
  right: 250px;
  height: 400px;
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: #FFFAFA; 
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid red;  
}

#second-sheet {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 250px; 
  right: 250px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  top: 650px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: #FFFAFA; 
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

**and the js:**

```
$('#the-sheet, #second-sheet').draggable( {
    appendTo: "body",
    scrollSpeed: 600,
    snap: false,
});
```

What I want is to be able to drag these around to a certain amount, yet they can be dragged to the right, thus expanding the width, and getting dragged past my desired width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a wrapper to "contain" the draggable items.

```
$('#the-sheet, #second-sheet').draggable( {
    appendTo: "body",
    scrollSpeed: 600,
    snap: false,
    containment: "#containment-wrapper"
});
```

Example snippet to show behavior -

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( ".box" ).draggable({ containment: "#containment-wrapper" })
})
```

```css
.box{
  
    left:50px;
    top:50px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: red
}

#containment-wrapper{
   width:300px;
   height:300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="containment-wrapper">
    <div class="box"></div>

</div>
```